# I can't seem to get the Body to stay below the head?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a sticky header to stay at the top of the window even when you scroll down, but the text in the body is showing up where the header should be. How do I keep it below?

```
<html>
<head>
<div style="position:Fixed;height:60px;width:100%;background-color:#121212""
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example Title</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color:#C5C5C5;">
    <p> Hello!
</body>
```

Comment: Its gone completely wrong dude...you are putting a `<div>` in `<head>`.

Comment: You are mistaking what the `<head>` element is for.

Comment: Itscalled blasphamecy. how cML element div in side <head> tag???? Its wrong

Comment: Alright thanks sorry for the dumb problem I just started learning html an hour ago.

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/H2Hm8/)

```
<body style="background-color: #C5C5C5;">
    <div class="head">
        <p>Hello!</p>
    </div>
    <div>Your content here.</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are wrongly implementing the html, head tag
div should stay within  tag

```
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example Title</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color:#C5C5C5;">
<div style="position:Fixed;height:60px;width:100%;background-color:#121212"></div>
    <p> Hello!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use div within `<head>` tag.

The HTML `<div>` element is found within the  tag.

Below example is, body with scroll.
check this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeyashri/R6eZF/)**

```
<body style="background-color:#C5C5C5;">
    <div style="position:Fixed;height:60px;width:100%;background-color:#121212"></div>
    <p style="height:1000px;position:relative;display:block;top:60px;"> Hello! </p>
</body>
```

The `<head>` element must include a title for the document, and can include scripts, styles, meta information.

The following elements can go inside the  element:

```
<title>
<style>
<base>
<link>
<meta>
<script>
<noscript>
```